# How to write the correct sum function?

Tags: php, laravel, sum, average

I want to find the total amount of profit and the average in the sales table of each person who sells it. How to use the sum and average functions correctly?

```
public function index()
{
  $sales_data = Auth::user()->sales()->paginate(30);
  $sum = $sales_data['sales']->sum('profit');
  $average = $sales_data['sales']->average('profit');
  $amount = $sales_data->total();
  return view('sales_page.index', ['user' => Auth::user()], compact('sales_data', 'amount', 'sum', 'average'));
}
```

Comment: Since your are paginating you are only getting the `avg` and `sum` of the paginated collection.

Answer (score 0):

Run collection function on collection object.

use `collect()` function to wrap your `$sales_data` and use `count()` instead of `total()`.

```
public function index()
{
  $sales_data = Auth::user()->sales()->paginate(30);
  $sum = collect($sales_data['sales'])->sum('profit');
  $average = collect($sales_data['sales'])->average('profit');
  $amount = collect($sales_data)->count();
  return view('sales_page.index', ['user' => Auth::user()],compact('sales_data', 'amount', 'sum', 'average'));
}
```